# Return strings from table values Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to learn how to print strings from a value in a table. For example.

```
TestTable = { "Apples" = 0, "Oranges" = 1, "Grapes" = 1, "Bananas" = 0}

for i=1, #TestTable do
   if TestTable[i] == 1 then
      print(TestTable[i]) --> Oranges Grapes
   end
end
```

Not sure if that made sense, but I want to print all the strings with the 1 value.

Comment: BTW, your table constructor is incorrect, change `"Apples" = 0` to either `Apples = 0` or `["Apples"] = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the `__len` metamethod is defined, the `#` operator can only be used on a sequence, but `TestTable` is not one.

You can use `pairs` to iterate the table:

```
TestTable = { Apples = 0, Oranges = 1, Grapes = 1, Bananas = 0}

for k, v in pairs(TestTable) do
    if v == 1 then
        print(k)
    end
end
```

Comment: It works. I am curious why "apples", "oranges", etc don't need quotes?

Comment: @BenjaminCondrea It's syntactic sugar. See [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html).